# concordion assertEquals limitation

Tags: concordion

Concordion version of **assertEquals** allows to compare a method return value with the HTML element inner value, like

p concordion:assertEquals="getGreeting()">Hello World!

However in many cases, the expected value is generated dynamically during the test execution and is not known in advance. How to use Concordion assertEquals in that case? How to pass the expected value into the assertEquals?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered in the Concordion group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/concordion/9hkcXCgwqWU

Did the answers help you?
If not, what do you need additionally?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Final solution from the [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/concordion/9hkcXCgwqWU) referenced in the previous answer:

html:

```
<span concordion:execute="#result = getResults()"></span>
<p><span concordion:assertTrue="#result.matches">They match!</span>
Primary email is: <span concordion:echo="#result.primaryEmail"></span>
Secondary email is: <span concordion:echo="#result.secondaryEmail">
</span></p>
```

fixture:

```
import static org.concordion.api.MultiValueResult.multiValueResult;

public MultiValueResult getResults() {
    return multiValueResult()
            .with("primaryEmail", "t...@tfwright.co.nz")
            .with("secondaryEmail", "t...@tfwright.co.nz")
            .with("matches", true);
}
```

Comment: It was the reference from the previous post. But ok.